# PHP - Problema com acentuação no loop em uma string

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tendo problema com loop em strings com caracteres especiais, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue o exemplo:

```
$letras = 'nós';
$numero = strlen($letras);
for($j = 0; $j < $numero; $j++){
    echo $letras[$j]."-";
}
```

Segue o resultado do código acima:
http://codepad.org/3EZ5bpUl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente fazer assim:

```
$letras = utf8_decode('nós');
$numero = strlen($letras);
for($j = 0; $j < $numero; $j++){
   echo utf8_encode($letras[$j])."-";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o `utf8_decode` para converter a string e após isto o `utf8_encode` para fazer a impressão de maneira correta.

```
 <?php
    $letras = utf8_decode('nós');
    $numero = strlen($letras);
    for($j = 0; $j < $numero; $j++){
        echo utf8_encode($letras[$j]."-");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode também utilizar o `mb_substr`, ou até mesmo regex.

---

```
$frase = 'nós';
$tamanho = mb_strlen($frase);

for($posicao = 0; $posicao < $tamanho; $posicao++){

    echo mb_substr($frase, $posicao, 1, "UTF-8") . '-';

}
```

**[Teste isto aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/864ea02533dabaf38b7ee3ad0a4491348d627e89)**

Dessa forma o `mb_substr` irá obter a letra da `$posicao`, como ele está definido para UTF-8 não há nenhum problema com caracteres multibytes.

Isso também é compatível com frases do tipo `您是否使用了翻译`, ele irá retornar:

```
您-是-否-使-用-了-翻-译-
```

*As demais respostas, usando utf8_decode, retornariam `?-?-?-?-?-?-?-?-`.*

---

Um outro caso seria criar algo como o `str_split`, porém compatível com caracteres com mais de um byte, *não existe mb_str_split*.

Você poderia utilizar o `preg_split`.

```
$frase = 'nós';
$tamanho = mb_strlen($frase);

$letras = array_filter(preg_split('//u', $frase));

foreach($letras as $letra){

    echo $letra . '-';

}
```

**[Teste isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/363cbdcb7ca0265c27cc9fc095be5280674f033c)**

Neste caso o `preg_split` é responsável por criar uma array, por cada Unicode, logo ele criará um:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(1) "n"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "ó"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "s"
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Como não queremos os espaços vazios, removemos com o `array_filter`.